# Crystal report with runtime n columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Hi I have similar problem,

I have following out put.

Name     Date1  Date2  Date3  Date4  Date5 ............... Daten..... Date z....   Toatal hr

Project1  2        -          2        3       1     ....... 8  ........... 1 ....   100

Project2  -        3          -        -        2     ....... 8  ........... 1 ....   150

Project3  2        3          -        2        -    ....... 8  ........... 1 ....    50

Project3  2        -          2        3        4    ....... 8   ........... 1 .....  50

.

.

.

Project N.....................................................................................

.

.
**Tatal hr 9      8     10    11....................................................   500**

Name is the Name of Employee

Dates are the dates in month that will depend on user selection i can be one day  or month or any no of dates..

Projects. name of projects done by employee in that time range.

all the data in the data base

Please help me to create the report as above

thank you.

Gowrishankar .

Answer (score 1):

this is for desktop application same way you can implement in asp.net

**http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Dynamic_Crystal_Report.aspx**